# Search list items (list has path that extracted using OS Walk) in a csv file. If it’s not available, then perform some action

Tags: python, pandas

I wanted to check each item of this list (Filepath_list) in a DataFrame (from a csv) that has list of path.

If it’s there than I will skip and check for next item in the list. If it not their than I will do some processing.

The code I am using is:

```
l = os.listdir(dir_path)

filepath_list = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_path):
    for f in files:
        if 'Apr.log' in f:
            filepath_list.append(os.path.join(root,f))

df_path_list_csv = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\ABC6\OneDrive - ABB\Files\Folder List.csv")

for g in filepath_list:
    if df_path_list_csv['Detail'].str.contains(g).any():
        print(g)
```

The error I am getting is:

> incomplete escape \U at position 2

Can anyone please help me with correcting the error in this code.
Is it because of backlash? If yes, how can I correct it. I tried replacing "\" with "/" but still its not working..

The variable Filepath_list has "\\" while df_path_list_csv dataframe has "\"

```
Filepath_list = 
['C:\\Users\\ABC6\\OneDrive - ABB\\Job Files\\SA_R 1_Ret\\13Mar22\\Apr.log',
 'C:\\Users\\ABC6\\OneDrive - ABB\\Job Files\\SA_Run 2_Dri\\28Mar22\\Apr.log',
 'C:\\Users\\ABC6\\OneDrive - ABB\\Job Files\\SA_Well_Run 2_Dri\\29Mar22\\Apr.log']

df_path_list_csv:
0   C:\Users\ ABC6\OneDrive - ABB\Job Files...
1   C:\Users\ ABC6\OneDrive - ABB\ Job Files...
```

Comment: In a python string the backslash char '\' is used to escape a special char, and is not interpreted litterally as a backslash. So just as you have in your variable Filepath_list just use double backslash in your pd.read_csv call with something like ```pd.read_csv(r"C:\\Users\\ABC6\\...")```

Comment: Thank you, Yannick, for replying, 
While reading the CSV its working fine. 
Problem is when I am comparing the file_Path stored in variable Filepath_list with the paths stored in CSV to identity new files. The code is not working.
The csv files has path stored with single backslash “\” while variable has path with double backslash “\\”
I also tried with replace but its not working.

Answer (score 1):

By default the `contains` method of pandas assume that the pattern used is a regular expression and so identify a backslash as an escape char. To avoid this behavior and use your pattern as litteral string you need to set the `regex` parameter to `False`.

```
l = os.listdir(dir_path)

filepath_list = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_path):
    for f in files:
        if 'Apr.log' in f:
            filepath_list.append(os.path.join(root,f))

# As said in my comment just double the backslash to avoid the error you get
df_path_list_csv = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\ABC6\\OneDrive - ABB\\Files\\Folder List.csv")

for g in filepath_list:
    # Here you have to set to False the `regex` parameter of the `contains` method
    if df_path_list_csv['Detail'].str.contains(g, regex=False).any():
        print(g)
```